# Why Do I get OutOfRange Exception in GetOrdinal Function of this CLOB field?

Tags: c#, oracle, select, clob

This is the sample of my code.  The field FUNCTION_SCRIPT is a CLOB field (the only CLOB field) in my table IS_FUNCTION

```
public void ReadFunction(string FName, out string fContent) {
    OracleCommand command = _connection.CreateCommand();
    OracleTransaction transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
    command.Transaction = transaction;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT TO_CLOB(TO_NCLOB(FUNCTION_SCRIPT)) FROM IS_FUNCTION where FNAME=:fName ";
    command.Parameters.Add("FName", OracleType.NVarChar).Value = FName;
    OracleDataReader odr = command.ExecuteReader();
    int temp = odr.GetOrdinal("FUNCTION_SCRIPT");
    OracleLob myLob = odr.GetOracleLob(temp);
    fContent = (String)myLob.Value;
    odr.close();
}
```

I get an out of range exception when `temp = odr.GetOrdinal("FUNCTION_SCRIPT")` statement is executed.  Have no idea why?  I have been trying to read this CLOB field for few hours now. This is the closest I have come. Your help would be highly appreciated.

p.s. Could it be that my SELECT statement is problematic?  I have been taking code from different references.

Comment: Although we can't see all your code, holding a global connection open might not be the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions and helps. I found that my problem was resolved by adding a

```
 if(odr.Read())
            {
                int temp = odr.GetOrdinal("FUNCTION_SCRIPT");
                OracleLob myLob = odr.GetOracleLob(temp);
                fContent = (String)myLob.Value;
            }
```

In other words, I was missing the statement odr.Read after the ExecuteReader() statement.

Comment: I got you. But you still need to call `if(odr.HasRows)` so that it doesn't try to read when there are no rows. `.Read()` positions to the first record and then the next record. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT TO_CLOB(TO_NCLOB(FUNCTION_SCRIPT)) AS FUNCTION_SCRIPT FROM IS_FUNCTION where FNAME=:fName ";
```

Right now your query does not have a name because you've applied a function to the name so you need to ALIAS it to give it a name e.g `AS FUNCTION_SCRIPT`

### UPDATE

```
OracleDataReader odr = command.ExecuteReader();
if(odr.HasRows)
{
  int temp = odr.GetOrdinal("FUNCTION_SCRIPT");
  OracleLob myLob = odr.GetOracleLob(temp);
  fContent = (String)myLob.Value;
}
else
   throw new Exception("No rows returned from database");
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution. Now I get "No Data Exists for Row or Column " error.  Any other ideas?  Thanks

Comment: You need to check if data is returned from your database. See my update

Comment: That did not work either. Now I am getting no rows or columns exist within the if(odr.HasRows) {} body.