# How to read a CLOB field into a C# variable?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why Do I get OutOfRange Exception in GetOrdinal Function of this CLOB field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574341/why-do-i-get-outofrange-exception-in-getordinal-function-of-this-clob-field)

```
I need to read a CLOB field from an ORACLE table int a C# variable of type String. Does anyone know how to accomplish this task?
```

This is what I have done but I am getting an IndexOutofRange when calculating the GetOrdinal of the field.  Thanks in advance.

```
 public void ReadFunction(string FName, out string fContent) 
{ 
    OracleCommand command = _connection.CreateCommand(); 
    OracleTransaction transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction(); 
    command.Transaction = transaction; 
    command.CommandText = "SELECT TO_CLOB(TO_NCLOB(FUNCTION_SCRIPT)) FROM IS_FUNCTION where   FNAME=:fName "; 
    command.Parameters.Add("FName", OracleType.NVarChar).Value = FName; 
    OracleDataReader odr = command.ExecuteReader(); 
    int temp = odr.GetOrdinal("FUNCTION_SCRIPT"); 
    OracleLob myLob = odr.GetOracleLob(temp); 
    fContent = (String)myLob.Value; 
    odr.close(); 
}
```

Comment: erm?, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574341/why-do-i-get-outofrange-exception-in-getordinal-function-of-this-clob-field

Comment: I need help badly, and I thought maybe I need to improve my question title.

Comment: @user1298925 then you should edit the title of your original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the code to get the  Blob, then you should cast it as astring in the way you need it. I do not know the format you need.

```
  // create and open connection
  // change for your environment
  string connStr = "User Id=pm; Password=pm; Data Source=orcllx; Pooling=false";
  OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connStr);
  try
  {
    con.Open();
  }
  catch (OracleException ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }

  // statement to get a blob
  string sql = "select ad_composite from print_media where product_id=3106 and
               ad_id=13001";

  // create command object
  // InitialLOBFetchSize
  //  defaults to 0
  OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con);

  cmd.InitialLOBFetchSize = 8192;

  // create a datareader
  OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

  // read the single row result
  try
  {
    dr.Read();
  }
  catch (OracleException ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }

  // use typed accessor to retrieve the blob
  OracleBlob blob = dr.GetOracleBlob(0);

  // create a memory stream from the blob
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(blob.Value);

  // set the image property equal to a bitmap
  // created from the memory stream
  pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(ms);
```

Comment: The dr.Read() was the missing link. . Just as a side, I was told that if you include data in your sql Select statement, that is considered a SQL Injection Attack which needs to be avoided.  I thought I share that piece of knowledge with you. Hope it is useful.

Comment: I didn't have to set the `InitialLOBFetchSize` - probably not necessary, but not a bad option, I guess.  It's actually common to get the blob to a byte array, which can be done with `byte[] array = new byte[blob.Length]; blob.Read(array, 0, (int)array.Length);`.  And really, it should use an `if (dr.HasRows) { ... }` conditional where the blob is then retrieved, and all of that would go inside. In WPF, you have to create a new `BitmapImage` and assign to its `StreamSource` a `MemoryStream`, like above, but there are a few other options to declare (`BitmapCreateOptions, BitmapCacheOption`).

Comment: The question is about CLOB though, not BLOB...