# LISTAGG alternative in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am kind of newbie in Oracle.
Got stuck in the below:
I have the below 2 tables:

**Site:**

```
**SiteID|SiteName** 
1      Sydney
2      Newyork
3      Delhi
```

**People:**

```
**RecordID|PeopleID|SiteID**
1         1        1
2         1        2
3         2        2
4         3        1
5         3        2
6         3        3
```

Now in my query I want an output something like this:

```
**PeopleID | AssignedSites**
1          Sydney,NewYork
2          Newyork
3          Sydney,NewYork,Delhi
```

- Few more points:

-The solution should work in Oracle 10g as well as 11g also.

-I have given small subset of data in the above example for brevity.But, in my prod scenario, one Person can be associated with 1000+ locations and there could 1000+ such person, so the solution should not break in that case!

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any function in oracle similar to group\_concat in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-to-group-concat-in-mysql)

Comment: You need to emphasize Oracle 10g, because the obvious solution (`listagg()`) was introduced in Oracle 11.

Comment: Yes, I had mentioned Oracle 10g.

Comment: @OP - See this page for solution for 10g - https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques

Comment: Why do you need this? I assume it is not for reporting (no one will read a report showing 1000+ persons, and for each, 1000+ locations separated by comma). Do you need this for further processing? If so, then concatenating locations in a long comma-separated string is almost surely the wrong approach - very hard to maintain, and very likely a performance killer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using `XMLAGG` like this:

```
select
    p.PeopleID,
    rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, s.SiteName, ',')).extract('//text()').getclobval(), ',')
from people p
join site s on p.SiteID = s.SiteID
group by p.PeopleID;
```

If you need the concatenation in a particular order, say increasing order of SiteId, then add an `order by` clause in the xmlagg:

```
select
    p.PeopleID,
    rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, s.SiteName, ',')
                   order by s.SiteId).extract('//text()').getclobval(), ',')
from people p
join site s on p.SiteID = s.SiteID
group by p.PeopleID;
```

#### EDIT:

If you want display result for all those people which are assigned to site 100:

```
select p.PeopleID,
    rtrim(xmlagg(
                xmlelement(e, s.SiteName, ',') order by s.SiteId
            ).extract('//text()').getclobval(), ',')
from people p
join site s on p.SiteID = s.SiteID
join (
    select distinct PeopleID
    from people
    where siteID = 1
    ) p2 on p.PeopleID = p2.PeopleID
group by p.PeopleID;
```

Comment: getting the error:ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
19011. 00000 -  "Character string buffer too small" 
*Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back
*Action:   Get the result as a lob instead

Comment: @user2948533 - That's because of the string limit. You can get a CLOB instead. Updated the answer.  Can you try now?

Comment: Perfect, I just hope that my middle tier code(C#) will be able to handle this datatype(clob).thanks a ton!

Comment: @user2948533 - Cheers :). Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574341/why-do-i-get-outofrange-exception-in-getordinal-function-of-this-clob-field) will be of some help.

Comment: one quick question: if I have to filter the above query by SiteID, i.e., something like where SiteID='100', how to do that?I am getting:ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression" error.

Comment: Add the where clause before the group by and after the join condition

Comment: Actually in that case it is showing only the sitename whose siteid=100, but I want to display all the people and their assigned site who are assigned to siteid=100  as the expected output I have mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

`listagg()` is the obvious choice, but it is not available in Oracle 10. However, even in Oracle 11, `listagg()` is limited to strings of length 4,000, and you explicitly say "Person can be associated with 1000+ locations".

There are ways around this, using CLOBs, XML, and no doubt other solutions as well. However, what use is a list of locations thousands and thousands of characters long? With so many locations, you are not going to be able to put the result in a standard `varchar2()` field.

Perhaps summarizing them in the database this way is not the best solution to your actual problem.

Comment: I think I am close to it, just need a small help: I have created a function GetSiteName, which returns the site name against the SiteID. Now I am using the below xmlagg where in I need to call this function GetSiteName:

Comment: @GurV, I think I am close to the solution, I have posted below my approach, only stuck at calling my function from within xmlagg,Can you please help?

Comment: @Gordon, I agree, bur this is something existing behavior in the application.But can you please throw some light on my below approach?Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I am close to it, just need a small help: I have created a function GetSiteName, which returns the site name against the SiteID. Now I am using the below xmlagg where in I need to call this function GetSiteName:

```
select PeopleID, rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e,  clint.GetSiteName(SiteID)   || ',')).extract ('//text()'), ',') SITEIDS
from client.People group by    PeopleID;/
```

Basically need help in calling the function from inside xmlagg, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I just needed an alternative for listagg on oracle 10g and found one in this page https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.

just use wm_concat, albeit it is not supported by oracle and has been droped in 12c.

with the example above:

```
select
    p.PeopleID,wm_concat(s.SiteName)
from people p
join site s on p.SiteID = s.SiteID
group by p.PeopleID;
```