# Oracle SQL - ListAgg - ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-bi

I have a table structure as below

```
PERSON_ID | SUFFIX | Details
-----------------------------
12345     | Mr     | ABC
12345     | Mr     | DEF
12345     | Mr     | GHI
```

This is my SQL

```
SELECT PERSON_ID
    ,SUFFIX
    ,LISTAGG(Details, ' ') WITHIN
GROUP (
        ORDER BY PERSON_ID
        ) AS Deets
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY PERSON_ID
    ,SUFFIX
```

So I want to put multiple rows into a single column. However, I get the following error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Any ideas why this is happening? My `TABLE_NAME` was built using a `WITH AS` statement. I can pull data from `TABLE_NAME` just fine, group the data and all the "normal" stuff

**Full Code**

```
WITH
person_id
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT person_id
    FROM PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F
),

suffix AS (
SELECT person_id, suffix 
FROM PER_PERSON_NAMES_F 
WHERE
    NAME_TYPE = 'GLOBAL' 
     AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(EFFECTIVE_START_date) AND TRUNC(EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) 
GROUP BY person_id, suffix
)
,
person_id_data
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT person_id
    FROM PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M
    WHERE person_id IN (SELECT person_id FROM person_id)
    AND ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE = 'ACTIVE' 
),

-- GETTING NUMBERS
Contact_Phone_Numbers As (SELECT 
    PERSON_ID, 
    OBJECT_VERSION_NUMBER, 
    PHONE_ID, 
    DATE_FROM, 
    DATE_TO, 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PHONE_TYPE,'O','Other'),'HM','Home Mobile'),'HF','Home Fax'),'H3','Third Home'),'H2','Second Home'),'H1','Home'),'WM','Work Mobile'),'WF','Work Fax'),'W3','Third Work'),'W2','Second Work'),'W1','Work') AS PHONE_TYPE, 
    PHONE_NUMBER, 
    SEARCH_PHONE_NUMBER, 
    COUNTRY_CODE_NUMBER 

FROM 
    PER_PHONES 

WHERE 
    PERSON_ID IN (SELECT person_id FROM person_id_data))
,

NEARLY_THERE AS (
    SELECT A.PERSON_ID, A.PHONE_TYPE, A.PHONE_NUMBER, B.SUFFIX
    FROM Contact_Phone_Numbers A
    LEFT JOIN suffix B
    ON A.PERSON_ID = B.PERSON_ID
    ORDER BY A.PERSON_ID
), 

SO_CLOSE AS (
SELECT PERSON_ID, CONCAT(PHONE_TYPE, CONCAT (' - ' , PHONE_NUMBER)) AS THE_DETAILS, SUFFIX
FROM NEARLY_THERE
ORDER BY PERSON_ID
),

FINAL AS (
    SELECT * FROM SO_CLOSE
)

SELECT PERSON_ID, SUFFIX, LISTAGG(THE_DETAILS, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PERSON_ID) AS Deets
FROM FINAL 
GROUP BY PERSON_ID, SUFFIX
```

Comment: Your code works fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=756b9baa2374499e0d2e7ba101395106.  Perhaps you have a bad character in the code you are actually running.

Comment: VERSION (12.1.0.2.0) - Using Oracle BI sitting within Oracle Fusion

Comment: if you remove the `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PERSON_ID) AS Deets` does the query run? How about if you remove the `LISTAGG`?

Comment: @CaiusJard [his](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions101.htm#SQLRF30030) version should support `WITHIN GROUP` clauses just fine.

Comment: I know, I'm just curious to see at what point it starts working

Comment: First: ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword. Second: It does bring data if I do select * from table_name

Comment: What does `SELECT PERSON_ID, LISTAGG(SUFFIX, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PERSON_ID) FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY PERSON_ID` do?

Comment: Is your `Details` column case sensitive? Does it need `"Details"` ? (Just wondering about the curious Titlecase presentation compard to the other columns - though I would have expected a different error message for this tbh)

Comment: @CaiusJard - same error. Also I amended script to be all same case and same error.

Comment: How are you running the query? In application code or a Oracle SQL IDE? Pretty that is where the error is comming from because your query is correct.

Comment: Oracle BI when creating a data model

Comment: Can you workaround it (for now) with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609917/listagg-alternative-in-oracle-10g) for example?

Comment: This seems to be working @RaymondNijland

Comment: Just guessing now (based on something i found on asktom) - what does `SELECT PERSON_ID, SUFFIX, EVALUATE_AGGR('LISTAGG(%1,%2) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY %3 )',Details,',',PERSON_ID) FROM TABLE_NAME 
GROUP BY PERSON_ID, SUFFIX` do?

Comment: @CaiusJard ORA-00904: "EVALUATE_AGGR": invalid identifier

Comment: No idea why your code does not work, but i have a feeling the nesting CTE's and reusing of the aliases might mess it up when using `LISTAGG` on it?

Answer (score 0):

(This is more of a comment but far too much/formatting for an actual comment)

What happens if you run the non-CTE version?

```
SELECT 
  paam.person_id, 
  ppnf.suffix,
  LISTAGG(
    CONCAT(
      DECODE(pp.PHONE_TYPE,'O','Other','HM','Home Mobile','HF','Home Fax','H3','Third Home','H2','Second Home','H1','Home','WM','Work Mobile','WF','Work Fax','W3','Third Work','W2','Second Work','W1','Work'),
      ' - ',
      pp.PHONE_NUMBER
    ),
    ' '
  ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PERSON_ID) as Deets

FROM 
  PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M paam
  INNER JOIN 
  PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F papf
  ON paam.person_id = papf.person_id

  INNER JOIN 
  PER_PHONES pp
  ON
    paam.person_id = pp.person_id

  LEFT JOIN 
  PER_PERSON_NAMES_F ppnf
  ON 
    paam.PERSON_ID = ppnf.PERSON_ID AND
    ppnf.NAME_TYPE = 'GLOBAL' AND
    TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(ppnf.EFFECTIVE_START_date) AND TRUNC(ppnf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) 

WHERE
  paam.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE = 'ACTIVE' 

GROUP BY PERSON_ID, SUFFIX
```

Note; some minor syntax errors and result differences may be seen as this query omits a few DISTINCT operations that the CTE form had. I recommend you fix it up without the listagg/group so there aren't repeated rows (sort your where clause/join conditions out so Cartesian products are eliminated rather than distincting them away later)

i.e. Fix this:

```
SELECT 
  paam.person_id, 
  ppnf.suffix,

    CONCAT(
      DECODE(pp.PHONE_TYPE,'O','Other','HM','Home Mobile','HF','Home Fax','H3','Third Home','H2','Second Home','H1','Home','WM','Work Mobile','WF','Work Fax','W3','Third Work','W2','Second Work','W1','Work'),
      ' - ',
      pp.PHONE_NUMBER
    )

FROM 
  PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M paam
  INNER JOIN 
  PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F papf
  ON paam.person_id = papf.person_id

  INNER JOIN 
  PER_PHONES pp
  ON
    paam.person_id = pp.person_id

  LEFT JOIN 
  PER_PERSON_NAMES_F ppnf
  ON 
    paam.PERSON_ID = ppnf.PERSON_ID AND
    ppnf.NAME_TYPE = 'GLOBAL' AND
    TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(ppnf.EFFECTIVE_START_date) AND TRUNC(ppnf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE) 

WHERE
  paam.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE = 'ACTIVE'
```

Then reintroduce the LISTAGG