# oracle SQL Concatenate 2 columns based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle, string-concatenation

let's say i have a table :

```
+----+------------+------------+
| ID |   NAME1    |     NAME2  |
+----+------------+------------+
| A1 |    DAVE    |    DAN     |
| A1 |    DOR     |    MON     |
| A2 |    STEPHAN |    ARKEL   |
| A3 |    ASH     |    CATCHAM |
| A4 |    RON     |    DON     |
| A4 |    OFIR    |    DOL     |
| A4 |    OFRA    |    SOL     |
+----+------------+------------+
```

i want to concatenate based on ID , if the next row has the same id add both names like below :

```
+----+-----------------------------------+
| ID |             NEW_NAME              |
+----+-----------------------------------+
| A1 |    DAVE~~DAN^^DOR~~MON            |
| A2 |    STEPHAN~~ARKEL                 |
| A3 |    ASH~~CATCHAM                   |
| A4 |    RON~~DON^^OFIR~~DOL^^OFRA~~SOL |
+----+-----------------------------------+
```

Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
select
  id,
  listagg(name1 || '~~' || name2, '^^') 
    within group (order by name1, name2) as new_name
from t
group by id
```

See running example at [SQL<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=76417c0392f985b51efefc6224c2ac0c).

Comment: does it matter if my server is 11g?
i get an error 
[42000][923] ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected Position: 114

Comment: This page (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) shows it's available in Oracle 11g release 2.

Comment: it appears i have 10g. . . and its not supported.  thank you very much for your help !!!

Comment: for version 10 you can use XmlAgg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609917/listagg-alternative-in-oracle-10g