# how to return multiple values if a condition satisfy in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

how can we return multiple values if a condition is satisfy for ex
we can't create or edit the existing table

```
table= ITEMS

        ITEM  |.     TYPE
------------------------------------------
apple,         | fruit
onion,        | vegetable
mango          |fruit
apple          |edible         |
mango          | edible
onion         |edible

select case when item IN ('apple','mango') then ('fruit')
when item IN ('onion') then ('vegetable')
when team In ('apple','mango','onion') then ('edable')
end 
from ITEAMS
where item='apple'
```

### output

fruit
edible

AS apple  is a fruit and edible
please advice how could I achieve this in oracle sql
thanks in advance

Comment: Why not simply `SELECT TYPE from ITEMS WHERE ITEM = 'apple'`?

Comment: Are you really using Oracle 11g and Oracle 10g? They are very old and unsupported.

Answer (score 1):

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ITEMS (ITEM, TYPE) AS
SELECT 'apple', 'fruit'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'onion', 'vegetable' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'mango', 'fruit'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'apple', 'edible'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'mango', 'edible'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'onion', 'edible'    FROM DUAL;
```

If you want the values a rows then you can simply use the `WHERE` clause to filter the rows and do not need to use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   items
WHERE  item = 'apple';
```

Which outputs:

| ITEM | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| apple | fruit |
| apple | edible |

---

If you want the values as columns then you can `PIVOT` the table:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   items
       PIVOT (
         MAX('TRUE') FOR type IN (
           'fruit' AS fruit,
           'vegetable' AS vegetable,
           'edible' AS edible
         )
       )
WHERE  item = 'apple';
```

Which outputs:

| ITEM | FRUIT | VEGETABLE | EDIBLE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | TRUE | *null* | TRUE |

---

If you want the values as a comma-delimited string then in Oracle 11g you can `GROUP BY` and use `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT item,
       LISTAGG(type, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY type) AS types
FROM   items
WHERE  item = 'apple'
GROUP BY item;
```

Which outputs:

| ITEM | TYPES |
| --- | --- |
| apple | edible,fruit |

Oracle 10g does not support `LISTAGG` but there are [similar alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609917/listagg-alternative-in-oracle-10g).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6nJcq72O)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this example:

```
create table items (item varchar2(10), type varchar2(10));

insert into items values ('apple','fruit');
insert into items values ('onion','vegetable');
insert into items values ('mango','fruit');
insert into items values ('apple','edible');
insert into items values ('mango','edible');
insert into items values ('onion','edible');
```

You could get the output you are looking for with this query:

```
select item, listagg(type,' ') as attributes
from items
group by item;
```

But you might consider redesigning the table so that you don't have different types of attributes (edible vs fruit) stored in the same column.

Comment: Oracle 10g does not support `LISTAGG`